# multiply each columns of a matrix by a vector

Tags: r, matrix

I have

```
mat<-matrix(1:12,3)
vect<-c(2,2,2)
```

How can I multiply each column by the vector in order to obtain:

```
2,  8, 14, 20
4, 10, 16, 22
6, 12, 18, 24
```

Comment: It may have been more sensible to give an example that wasn't just repeating `2` for each value of `vect`

Comment: The question is unclear.  You may have to specify whether you need to multiply each row of `mat` with each element of `vect`.  But, your title is to `multiply each column of a matrix by a vector`.  In the example provided, `mat` has 4 columns and `vect` with 3 same element.  If the vect is different, i.e. `vect <- c(2,4,6)`, what would be the expected result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vect*mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    8   14   20
[2,]    4   10   16   22
[3,]    6   12   18   24
```

The vector `vect` is recycled by column. Better to experiment with different values to see the process.

Comment: @akrun 'recycled by column' to mean `2*[1,1], 4*[2,1], 6*[3,1], 2*[2,1], 4*[2,2]...` So to mean running down each column. I now see that 'column-wise can also mean `2*[1,1], 2*[2,1], 2*[3,1], 4*[2,1], 4*[2,2]...`